# Get elements of a list of strings that are "larger" than another string in python

Tags: python, list

I have a python list of strings and I need to check if the elements of that list contain a date larger than a specific value.

```
files = ["20_0506 Fee.csv",
         "20_0520 Fie.csv",
         "20_0603 Foe.csv",
         "20_0604 Fum.csv"]

latest = "20_0602"
```

`files` is a list of files with the date at the beginning of the file name. I need to get all of the files that are greater than the latest date, `latest`.

Is there a straightforward way to do this that I'm missing?

I tried to select the dates out of `files` using:

```
filedates = [i[:7] for i in files]
```

and then I selected the dates larger than `latest`:

```
noobs = [i for i in filedates if i >= latest]
```

But the problem is that I now end up with another list:

```
noobs
>>> ['20_0603', '20_0604']
```

I got stuck trying to figure out how to check for these strings in `files` and realized that I was running in circles.

In this example, the output should be:

```
["20_0603 Foe.csv", "20_0604 Fum.csv"]
```

What is the simplest way for me to get all of the files that have a "date" part of the filename that is larger than the "date" stored in `latest`?

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> files = ["20_0506 Fee.csv",
...          "20_0520 Fie.csv",
...          "20_0603 Foe.csv",
...          "20_0604 Fum.csv"]
>>>
>>> latest = "20_0602"
>>> [file for file in files if file > latest]
['20_0603 Foe.csv', '20_0604 Fum.csv']
```

A simple string comparison works here since the date is at the start of the filename and is in a standardized format.  You don't even need to bother with separating it from the rest of the string.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension to filter the values in `files` that have a date greater than or equal to `latest`:

```
files = ["20_0506 Fee.csv",
         "20_0520 Fie.csv",
         "20_0603 Foe.csv",
         "20_0604 Fum.csv"]

latest = "20_0602"

out = [f for f in files if f[:7] >= latest]
print(out)
```

Output:

```
['20_0603 Foe.csv', '20_0604 Fum.csv']
```

Note that because the parts of your date are in `YMD` order you can sort them directly as strings without conversion to a date-type object.

Answer (score 1):

Although, the solutions already given here will work perfectly fine, by comparing the string you will get the latest file.

This is just in case you wanted to go with datetime comparison.

Here, I went with a function take `fileName` and compares it with `latestDate`.

```
from datetime import datetime
def isGreaterThanLatest(fileName, latestDate):
    date,name = fileName.split()
    return datetime.strptime(date.strip(), "%y_%m%d") > latestDate 


files = ["20_0506 Fee.csv",
         "20_0520 Fie.csv",
         "20_0603 Foe.csv",
         "20_0604 Fum.csv"]

latestDate = datetime.strptime("20_0602", "%y_%m%d")

out = [f for f in files if isGreaterThanLatest(f, latestDate)]
print(out)
```

**Output:**

```
['20_0603 Foe.csv', '20_0604 Fum.csv']
```